How to resolve error with gtsummary tbl_summary: Error with "by = " argument
This code has been in an R Notebook for a few months and always worked, but now getting this error:
Error in `tbl_summary()`:
! Error processing `type` argument.
! Can't select columns that don't exist. ✖ Column `var4` doesn't exist.
ℹ Select among columns "var1", "var2", and "var3"

See sample code below:
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)

# created simple data
df_demo <- data.frame(
  var1 = rnorm(10),  # Continuous variable 1
  var2 = rnorm(10),  # Continuous variable 2
  var3 = sample(c("Group 1", "Group 2"), 10, replace = TRUE),  # Categorical variable 1
  var4 = sample(c("Yes", "No"), 10, replace = TRUE)  # Categorical variable 2
)

# Try running the tbl_summary function with 4 variables
PPF_table <- df_demo %>%
  subset(select = c(var1, var2, var3, var4)) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    missing = "no",
    by = var4,  # Group by categorical variable var4
    type = list(
      c(var1, var2) ~ "continuous",  # Treat var1 and var2 as continuous
      c(var3, var4) ~ "categorical"  # Treat var3 and var4 as categorical
    ),
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})", all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
    label = list(
      var1 ~ "Variable 1",
      var2 ~ "Variable 2",
      var3 ~ "Group",
      var4 ~ "Response"
    )
  ) %>%
  add_p(
    test = list(all_continuous() ~ "t.test", all_categorical() ~ "chisq.test"),
    pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2)
  ) %>%
  add_n()

# Print the table summary
PPF_table

I updated my R Studio (Version 2024.09.1+394 (2024.09.1+394)) and now it's not working. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling both R (R version 4.4.2 (2024-10-31) and RStudio, but no luck. I've tried updating my gt_summary and dplyr packages as well. The "by = " seems to be the issue.

The var4 column is your by variable, and therefore you can't assign it a summary type (since it's not a summary variable in the table). Just remove var4 from the type and label arguments, and you'll be good to go.

Thank you, not sure why the change, but it works again with removing var4 from type and label!

In v2.0 of gtsummary, there is improved messaging for users when they try to select columns that don't appear in the table. But the other side of that, is that you can only select columns that have summary stats in the table now.

@DanielD.Sjoberg, a experienced a similar experience with this update breaking the code execution. I believe the previous version was "tolerant" of the by variable being re-used downstream in label , and, although the update version looks safer, i feel a "breaking changes" warning/docs may be missing?
Removing the by variable solved the issue here too.

I see where you are coming from @GuedesBF. This particular situation is a little tricky for two reasons. First, I don't think I necessarily view it as a breaking change because these arguments do not apply the by variable. Rather it's improved messaging when the arguments are not being used as they are meant to be. These arguments were actually more permissive than just the by variable, and this update overall improves the experience of the user.

Second, to include the notification messaging in this situation would have been quite cumbersome and introduced some pretty strange code internally. I hope the updated messaging gives a pretty good idea of what the unexpected results are. Last note, it's always a good idea to use packages like renv to make your analyses robust to changes in any package. If you haven't already begun using it, I highly recommend it! Happy Coding!!

Thanks @DanielD.Sjoberg. I suffered a little because the update does not only provide a clear message as you state, but actually throws an error where code ran just fine. Took several minutes to debug and identify the package update as the source.
A similar thing happened with the labels argument in tbl_regression, which previously accepted named vectors, now requiring named lists.
Anyway, as projects get more complex, your recommendation for finer control of environment reproducibility become more and more important. Thanks for the awesome package, a go-to in my everyday research.
